# Are classes objects in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, class, metaclass

okay, so I understand that an object is an instance of a class that must be allocated and initialized, but are classes themselves objects?

I know when you create a new class it is an instance of something else, like NSObject. So, if this makes it a class, then objects can hold not only variables and methods, but other objects as well, right?

Sorry, this is probably really basic, but I am reading two books about cocoa and xcode and this point is a little unclear (probably because of my lack of experience in other languages).

Comment: I think you are talking about Meta Classes? http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[Here](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html) is a pretty good explanation of the matter by Greg Parker

Quoting:

> [...] Each Objective-C class is also an
>   object. It has an isa pointer and
>   other data, and can respond to
>   selectors. When you call a "class
>   method" like [NSObject alloc], you are
>   actually sending a message to that
>   class object.
>
> Since a class is an object, it must be
>   an instance of some other class: a
>   metaclass. The metaclass is the
>   description of the class object, just
>   like the class is the description of
>   ordinary instances. In particular, the
>   metaclass's method list is the class
>   methods: the selectors that the class
>   object responds to. When you send a
>   message to a class - an instance of a
>   metaclass - objc_msgSend() looks
>   through the method list of the
>   metaclass (and its superclasses, if
>   any) to decide what method to call.
>   Class methods are described by the
>   metaclass on behalf of the class
>   object, just like instance methods are
>   described by the class on behalf of
>   the instance objects.
>
> What about the metaclass? Is it
>   metaclasses all the way down? No. A
>   metaclass is an instance of the root
>   class's metaclass; the root metaclass
>   is itself an instance of the root
>   metaclass. The isa chain ends in a
>   cycle here: instance to class to
>   metaclass to root metaclass to itself.
>   The behavior of metaclass isa pointers
>   rarely matters, since in the real
>   world nobody sends messages to
>   metaclass objects. [...]

Further interesting reads:

[Understanding the Objective-C Runtime](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2010/01/understanding-objective-c-runtime.html) by Colin Wheeler
(search for paragraph titled "So Classes define objects…")

[What is a meta-class in Objective-C?](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html) by Matt Gallagher