# Are classes structs or struct pointer

Tags: objective-c, class, struct

If I'm not mistaken, structs mean objects, and struct pointers mean pointer to objects right? In an article, It says that classes are structs which means that they are objects.

```
Filter the list of all classes
The traditional definition of a class in Objective-C looks like this:

struct objc_class {
    Class isa;
    Class super_class;
    const char *name;
    long version;
    long info;
    long instance_size;
    struct objc_ivar_list *ivars;
    struct objc_method_list **methodLists;
    struct objc_cache *cache;
    struct objc_protocol_list *protocols;
    };
```

So, if it says that classes are structs, then how will they fit in the argument of `objc_msgSend(id self, SEL_cmd)` which requires a struct pointer which is of type `id`?

Comment: Do understand that there's a difference between a C++ "class" and "object" and the same terms in Objective-C.  An Objective-C "object" is a very specific sort of structure that conforms to Objective-C specifications.  It is implemented using C `struct` entities, but that fact can/should be ignored most of the time.  C and `struct` are, in essence, the "assembly language" underlying Objective-C.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Classes are structs, but `Class` is a pointer type, being defined as

```
typedef struct objc_class *Class;
```

and this answers the first part of the question.

Now, if you take a look at `<objc/objc.h>` you'll find

```
struct objc_class {
    Class isa  OBJC_ISA_AVAILABILITY;

 #if !__OBJC2__
    Class super_class                                        OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    const char *name                                         OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    long version                                             OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    long info                                                OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    long instance_size                                       OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    struct objc_ivar_list *ivars                             OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    struct objc_method_list **methodLists                    OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    struct objc_cache *cache                                 OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    struct objc_protocol_list *protocols                     OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
#endif

} OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
```

and in `<obj/runtime.h>` you'll find

```
/// Represents an instance of a class.
struct objc_object {
    Class isa  OBJC_ISA_AVAILABILITY;
};
```

meaning that in Objective-C 2.0 `objc_object` and `objc_class` are identical structs, both having an `isa` field.

That's why you can pass a `Class` where an `id` is required: [classes are objects after all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773054/are-classes-objects-in-objective-c).

You would normally expect a warning about the incompatible pointers type, but apparently the Obj-C compiler uses an ad-hoc treatment this specific case.
<s>I have no references to support this, though.</s>

#### EDIT

I finally found a reference in the clang source code:

In `ASTContext.cpp`, this is the `Class` declaration

```
TypedefDecl *ASTContext::getObjCClassDecl() const {
  if (!ObjCClassDecl) {
    QualType T = getObjCObjectType(ObjCBuiltinClassTy, 0, 0);
    T = getObjCObjectPointerType(T);
    TypeSourceInfo *ClassInfo = getTrivialTypeSourceInfo(T);
    ObjCClassDecl = TypedefDecl::Create(const_cast<ASTContext &>(*this),
                                        getTranslationUnitDecl(),
                                        SourceLocation(), SourceLocation(),
                                        &Idents.get("Class"), ClassInfo);
  }
  
  return ObjCClassDecl;
}
```

and this is the `id` declaration

```
TypedefDecl *ASTContext::getObjCIdDecl() const {
  if (!ObjCIdDecl) {
    QualType T = getObjCObjectType(ObjCBuiltinIdTy, 0, 0);
    T = getObjCObjectPointerType(T);
    TypeSourceInfo *IdInfo = getTrivialTypeSourceInfo(T);
    ObjCIdDecl = TypedefDecl::Create(const_cast<ASTContext &>(*this),
                                     getTranslationUnitDecl(),
                                     SourceLocation(), SourceLocation(),
                                     &Idents.get("id"), IdInfo);
  }
  
  return ObjCIdDecl;
}
```

In both cases the type is set to the result of `getObjCObjectPointerType`. This causes the compiler to consider both `Class` and `id` as pointers to Objective-C objects.

Answer (score 5):

> If I'm not mistaken, structs mean objects, and struct pointers mean pointer to objects right?

Mostly, yes. But since in Objective-C, objects (including classes) can only be manipulated using pointers, the shorthand "object" is used instead of a more correct "pointer to an object", even in pieces of official documentation.

> So, if it says that classes are structs, then how will they fit in the argument of `objc_msgSend()`?

They pass a pointer to a struct which is an object. `Class` is a typedef for `struct objc_class *`, whereas `id` is a typedef for `struct objc_object *`. Both are (non-function) pointers, and both structures contain an `isa` field, they can be used interchangeably as far as you know what you are doing.

Comment: I wrote pretty much the same thing, but I have a doubt: why isn't the compiler throwing an `Incompatible pointer types` when you pass a `struct objc_class *` to a function expecting a `struct objc_object *`? Having an identical layout shouldn't matter at compiler time, so I would expect a warning. What's the trick?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella The trick is that the compiler knows that `Class` and `id` are special types. With the same reasoning, you could expect `objc_msgSend(@"foo", @selector(length))` to emit a warning, because `struct __NSCFConstantString *` is not compatible with `struct objc_object *`, but these are built-in types as well.

Comment: Thanks, this confirms my intuition. Do you have any reference to support this?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Um, not any particular reference off the top of my head. You may find something interesting in the source of `clang`, though.

Comment: I understand. If I'll feel curious/patient enough during the afternoon I'll take a look at `clang`. +1 for the good answer, in any case.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Thanks. Well if you wait, in the meantime I can search the sources as well :)

Comment: I you feel like, that would be really interesting :)

Comment: I think I found the relevant piece of code. Check it out in my answer ;)

Comment: Oh and by the way, to my knowledge `__NSCFConstantString` is a subclass of `NSObject`. So no big deal there.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Well, yes, but `struct __NSCFConstantString *` and `struct objc_object *` are still incompatible types, with regards to the C type system.

Comment: sure but is `__NSCFConstantString` explicitly defined as a struct? I cannot find its declaration

Comment: @GabrielePetronella No, but all Objective-C objects are implicitly treated as a `struct` by the compiler. Even the GDB and LLDB debuggers adapt this convention, if I recall correctly.

Comment: I believe so. My point is simply that `__NSCFConstantString` is not a special case. Being a normal object is totally ok for the compiler not to emit any warning. I wouldn't expect `objc_msgSend(@"foo", @selector(length))` to emit a warning for instance.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39581/discussion-between-h2co3-and-gabriele-petronella)

Comment: just noticed the chat. I've added a few replies there. We definitely agree ;)

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Yay, that's nice! :) I've replied too.