# iOS / Objective-C - struct objc_class * and struct objc_object *

Tags: ios, objective-c, struct, objective-c-runtime

My understanding is that *objects* and *classes* in **Objective-C** are just *structs*.

Respectively they are just:

```
struct objc_class *
```

and:

```
struct objc_object *
```

***Question #1:***

```
objc_msgSend(id self, SEL _cmd);
```

`id` as far as I know is of type `struct objc_object *`

But when we call a class method, a class, which is of type `struct objc_class *`,

I would expect it to cause problem or shout out some kind of warning such as „Hey, wrong type here, my friend“.

But there isn’t.

- Why?

This only serves to fulfill my curiosity, because even without fully understanding this, it doesn’t seem to cause me any trouble (so far). But I would like to dig deep and learn the fundamentals / „peculiarities".

***Question #2:***

Since there is no warning according to my experience (relates to ***Question #1***), hence my not-so-sure assumption that they *could perhaps* be used interchangeably.

Can `struct objc_class *` and `struct objc_object *` *really* be used **interchangeably**?

If yes:

- Can you show me a scenario and a sample when / how / why we would need to use these interchangeably?
- What would be the **benefit** (if any), **disadvantages** (if any) and „**gotchas**“ (things to watch out for; if any) doing so?

Comment: [Related ressource](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-03-13-intro-to-the-objective-c-runtime.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are classes structs or struct pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469284/are-classes-structs-or-struct-pointer)

Comment: @Unheilig ugh, fair enough, that was in the chat. The thing is, every class is an object, so anywhere an object is expected, you can just throw in a class. Not in the other direction, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> My understanding is that objects and classes in Objective-C are just structs.

This isn't really true, particularly since ObjC2, and definitely isn't a good way of thinking about it. The "struct" in question has a single field (`isa`) defined. That's it. It's a "struct" in name only.

Note that under ARC objects and structs are treated differently by the compiler. Objects pointers will get special handling (including nil-initialization) that a struct pointer will not. The compiler will also apply `->` differently to an object than it does to a struct. A struct pointer must have a field with the name given after the `->`. `objc_object` only has one field (`isa`). Since class hierarchies can be defined and redefined at runtime, the compiler cannot evaluate `->` for an object at compile time as it does for a struct.

I make this point because in C++, objects and structs are just slightly different versions of the same thing, and you can easily swap between them. You cannot safely do that in ObjC. They're not nearly as similar.

> But when we call a class method, a class, which is of type `struct objc_class *`, I would expect it to cause problem…

[This is because classes are objects.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773054/are-classes-objects-in-objective-c) Objects are not defined in terms of being of type `objc_object`. They're defined in terms of having an `isa` field (it used to be a pointer, but now it might be a pointer, [or it might not](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2013/09/24/objc_explain_Non-pointer_isa.html)). This is part of the problem of assuming that the typedef is the important thing. It isn't. What matters is whether it acts like an object. Objective-C is a mostly duck-typed language. If it acts like an object, it's an object.

BTW, `NSProxy` also lives in this weird almost-an-object world. If you note its definition, it does not inherit from anything, but it does declare an `isa` field as its first ivar. That's the critical part of making it act like an object.

> Can struct objc_class * and struct objc_object * really be used interchangeably?

No. You can generally pass a class to anything that wants an object (since a class is an object), but you cannot pass an object to things that want a class.

Comment: Thanks for great answer. Ok, we could generally pass a class to anything that expects an object but we could not do the other way around, so is there some sort of "special mechanism" the compiler does to prevent an object passed to where a class is expected (but the other way round would be OK)?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a special mechanism. The ObjC compiler just won't accept things that aren't a `Class` when a `Class` is expected. If you typecast it, it'd probably compile. It'd just crash later. If you use the underlying `objc_*` types (which is rare), the compiler will treat it as C. But all that means is that in C, a pointer is a pointer (just like an `id` is an `id`). If you just created an automatic variable of type `struct objc_object`, you could probably make it compile, but it wouldn't work when the runtime got to it. It's not like C++ where most things are resolved at compile-time.

Answer (score 5):

I find this in runtime.h file.

```
struct objc_class {
    Class isa  OBJC_ISA_AVAILABILITY;

#if !__OBJC2__
    Class super_class                                        OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    const char *name                                         OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    long version                                             OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    long info                                                OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    long instance_size                                       OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    struct objc_ivar_list *ivars                             OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    struct objc_method_list **methodLists                    OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    struct objc_cache *cache                                 OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    struct objc_protocol_list *protocols                     OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
#endif

} OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;


struct objc_object {
    Class isa  OBJC_ISA_AVAILABILITY;
};
```

Both objc_class and objc_object has isa variable, isa in objc_object is point to Class which describes the instance and stores instance method list. Isa in objc_class is point to Class too but it is meta-class which describes the class and stores class method list.

[The link](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html) is useful to you.

I have simulate the condition.

```
struct A {
    int a ;
} ;

typedef struct A *PA ;

struct B {
    int a ;
    int b ;
} ;

void dosomething(PA pa)
{
    printf("%d", (*pa).a) ;
}

+ (void)hei
{
    struct B b ;
    b.a = 10 ;
    b.b = 20 ;
    // without forced cast, i will get a warning but work well
    dosomething((PA)&b) ;
}
```

You can use `struct B *` instead of `struct A *` because compiler and linker place `int a` in the same relative address.

Why compiler doesn't complain when we call class method which pass `struct objc_class *` to the `objc_msgSend(id self, SEL _cmd);`, in my opinion the compiler takes account of it.

Comment: It would be fine (though very dangerous). Struct fields are just offsets added to a base memory address. You can lay a struct definition over arbitrary `void*` memory if you want to. In a lot of ways, that's how ObjC works. Most of the object isn't actually "in" the struct. The struct just has one field. But you can use the struct to point to the beginning of the object, and it defines an `isa` field that maps to the first byte, just like in this example.

Comment: But trying to make use of this fact with ObjC objects is not going to go well. The runtime manages the memory how it wants to, and makes you very few promises on how it's going to lay out. It's interesting to know how it works under the covers, but it's dangerous to build things based on that. Apple can (and *has*) changed the internal representation of objects. The only correct interface is through the Runtime functions (or through normal Objective-C usage).