# How to declare a Class property in objective-c?

Tags: ios

How to declare a Class property in objective-c?

Like this:

`@property Class praise_usersClass;`

it's right?

Comment: `@property (nonatomic, strong) ClassName *praise_usersClass;`

Comment: I guess it should be like that since you can't release a `Class` 
@property(unsafe_unretained,nomatomic) Class praise_usersClass;

Comment: Do you mean class level properties, like static properties, which are attached to the class itself rather than an instance? If so, take a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695980/how-do-i-declare-class-level-properties-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C, `Class` is a pointer type and essentially also an object. So you can define a property as type `Class` just like any other object but you do not need to specify the pointer as it is part of the `typedef` definition.

Your example is fine:

```
@property Class praise_usersClass;
```

But FYI, note that you haven't specified any attributes so the defaults will apply:

```
@property (atomic,strong,readwrite) Class praise_usersClass;
```

For more information: [Are classes structs or struct pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469284/are-classes-structs-or-struct-pointer)