# memory management attribute when using Class type property in Objective-C ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

`Class` is a struct pointer, is it a object type or scalar, which I guess is the key to decide to use `strong`/`weak` or `assign`?

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C Class is an object and is instance of a metaclass. It is a retainable object pointer type. Reference: [clang.llvm.org](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#retainable-object-pointers) also this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773054/are-classes-objects-in-objective-c).

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class Human{
    var name:String!
    var passport:Passport!
   // weak var passport:Passport!

    init(name:String) {
      self.name = name
      print("Allocate Human")
  }

deinit {
    print("Deallocate Human")
}

}

class Passport {
   var country:String!
   var human:Human!

   init(country:String) {
     self.country = country
     print("Allocate Passport")
}
deinit {
    print("Deallocate Passport")
    }
}
```

**Lets see different scenario**
1.

```
Human.init(name: "Arjun")
```

**OUTPUT:**

// - Allocate Human

// - Deallocate Human

// Its automatically deallocate because its manage by ARC.

**2.**

```
var objHuman1: Human? = Human.init(name: "Arjun")
```

**OUTPUT**

// - Allocate Human

//Its not deallocate automatically because human class reference count 1 (objHuman1)

```
 objHuman1 = nil
```

**OUTPUT**

// - Deallocate Human

//Because its referece count is 0

```
var passport: Passport? = Passport.init(country: "India")
objHuman1?.passport = passport
passport = nil
```

**OUTPUT**

Allocate Human

Allocate Passport

*// Here is magic You can not deallocate passport. Because Human class has Storng reference of Passport.*

// But if you declare Weak property of passport variable in Human Class Like:

```
weak var passport:Passport!
```

**OUTPUT Will**

//Allocate Human

//Allocate Passport

//Deallocate Passport

That's a magic of Week and Strong property. Swift Default property is Strong.